# Sort and zip list in python

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python.
I have the following question:
I want to write a one-line code that produces the following outputs.
Given

```
Brands = ['Audi', 'VW', 'Benz'] 
Models = ['A4', 'Golf', 'C class']
```

returns:

```
Audi A4 
Benz C class
VW golf
```

This means ordered alphabetically by models.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and `sorted`. As zip returns tuples of (brand, model), this is directly in a perfect format for `sorted` to sort on brand-first.

```
out = list(map(' '.join, sorted(zip(Brands, Models))))
```

output:

```
['Audi A4', 'Benz C class', 'VW Golf']
```

As printed text:

```
print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, sorted(zip(Brands, Models)))))
```

output:

```
Audi A4
Benz C class
VW Golf
```

Using a more classical list comprehension:

```
[f'{brand} {model}' for brand, model in sorted(zip(Brands, Models))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I actually want output in string format:

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding ;)